# How do I assess whether two time series change together?

Tags: time-series, correlation

In this example, at timepoint 5, both signals move up together. I would like to quantify these similar movements, and ideally disregard the parts where the signals are almost constant.
What correlation or similarity measures would be best here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a [Granger causality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) which a statistical hypothesis test for determining whether one time series is useful in forecasting another. One time series is said to Granger-cause another time series if the lagged values of one times series provide statistically significant information about future values of another time series.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), as this algorithm calculates an optimal match between two given sequences. If you would like to implement it in Python (for example), I can recommend [DTAIDistance](https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The documentation of this project is also very helpful if you want to understand this method in detail.

Comment: But DTW would also count the constant parts as similar, wouldn't it? I would ideally like to disregard or at least give less weight to the parts where one or both are constant.